# Not able to insert an image path to db in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I don't know what  I am doing wrong here but can't seem to update an image path db.

I have tried to print $image both i controller and model,works fine but when I look into db it inserts word 'images'.

**Model:**

```
function update_profile_image($image, $id){
    $this->db->set('profile_thumb', $image);
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('vbc_property_images');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function property_profile_image_update() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $image = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->my_listings_model->update_profile_image($id, $image);
    $this->load->view('property-profile-image-update');
}
```

url is:

> http://localhost/admin/dashboard/property-profile-image-update/1/property_image_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change your model function as

```
function update_profile_image($id, $image)
```

because you are passing `$id` as first parameter while calling the `update_profile_image()` method in the controller.

Comment: Sorry no luck..  is it possible becoz I had that image in a different row as image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg... But if it prints as individual like image2.jpg then that shouldn't be the case, is it?